# Julia how to extend isless function

Tags: generics, julia

I am new to Julia and just learned that Julia can generate generic methods by changing the function signature.

```
function round_number(x::Float64)
  return round(x)
end

round_number(3.1415)
round_number(3)

function round_number(x::Int64)
  return x
end

round_number(3)
```

When I found the function `test_interpolated` cannot work with number and string, I tried to see if I can generate a new signature to extend the `isless`. Unfortunately, it did not work.

```
function test_interpolated(a, b)
  if a < b
      "$a is less than $b"
  elseif a > b
      "$a is greater than $b"
  else
      "$a is equal to $b"
  end
end

test_interpolated(3.14, 3.14)
test_interpolated(3.14, "3.14")

function isless(x::AbstractFloat, y::AbstractString)
  return x < float64(y)
end

test_interpolated(3.14, "3.14")
```

Did I misunderstand the concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that there is no `float64` function in Julia. To parse a string as a number you need to use the `parse` function:

```
parse(Float64, "3.14")
```

The second thing in your code is that:

```
function isless(x::AbstractFloat, y::AbstractString)
  return x < float64(y)
end
```

creates a **new function** named `isless` in your current module (most likely `Main` if you are working in e.g. REPL).

To add a method to the `isless` function defined in `Base` module you would have to write:

```
function Base.isless(x::AbstractFloat, y::AbstractString)
  return x < float64(y)
end
```

(note the `Base.` prefix)

Although Julia allows for it you should never do it in your code. This style is called *type piracy*, and is explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-type-piracy).

In short you are adding a method to a function from `Base` module and both `AbstractFloat` and `AbstractString` are also defined in `Base` module. The problem is that adding such a method might break other code that assumes in this case that `isless` when passed `AbstractFloat` and `AbstractString` throws an error.

The way you should define your function is e.g. as follows:

```
toreal(x::Real) = x

toreal(x::AbstractString) = parse(Float64, x)

function test_interpolated(a::Real, b::Real)
  if a < b
      "$a is less than $b"
  elseif a > b
      "$a is greater than $b"
  else
      "$a is equal to $b"
  end
end

test_interpolated(a, b) = test_interpolated(toreal(a), toreal(b))
```

In this way you ensure that you have one specific method with narrow signature implementing the logic for real numbers and other method for `test_interpolated` that has a  wide signature that performs conversion to appropriate types.

Note that I use `Real` not `AbstractFloat` as comparison with `<` is guaranteed to be defined across two `Real` values, and you most likely want your function to e.g. accept integers.

The approach I show is explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#man-methods-orthogonalize).

---

#### EDIT

Example of dispatch ambiguity. Use a fresh Julia 1.7.0 session:

```
julia> struct T end

julia> Base.propertynames(::T, ::Integer) = nothing

julia> propertynames(T(), true)
ERROR: MethodError: propertynames(::T, ::Bool) is ambiguous. Candidates:
  propertynames(x, private::Bool) in Base at reflection.jl:1666
  propertynames(::T, ::Integer) in Main at REPL[2]:1
```

Comment: Just a further example on how type piracy (often) breaks method dispatch: imagine a package that uses `typecode(::AbstractString) = 2` for a compile-time constant, then you define `typecode(::String) = 16`. That package is now broken for `String`s. Guarding against unintended type piracy is exactly why defining `isless` instead of `Base.isless` in your module makes a new function. The devs know that nobody can know all the names in Base, so this system lets you use any name you want contained within your module, and other modules can only use it by an explicit import.

Comment: So the type piracy is maintained by the Julia user?

Comment: It's more of a group effort, just at least 2 different people with different intentions accidentally writing methods that clash. You can avoid a method clash on your own with a simple guideline: 1) if none of the arguments are types you created, only make and extend functions you create, 2) if some of the arguments are types you created, then you may extend someone else's function. Also, multiple developers can collaborate to edit their libraries to fix clashes; this is also called type piracy but it's a good kind.

Comment: Indeed the last comment of BatWannaBe is a relevant case requiring collaboration. E.g. some functions in `Base` have a loose parametrization. Then, when you add methods to such functions for your types, you might unintentionally introduce method dispatch ambiguity. An example is `Base.propertynames(::T, ::Integer) = nothing` where `T` is your custom type. Such a definition creates dispatch ambiguity although you used your type `T` in the signature. This is fixable by adding `Base.propertynames(::T, ::Bool)` additionally in this case, but I just want to show you that you need to be careful.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the kind suggestions and tips :). I will dive more into Julia.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I tried your example and couldn't find a method call that causes a method ambiguity ( `propertynames(T(), true) works` ). I worked out another example, if one person creates `f(x::T, y::Int64) where T = 1`, and a 2nd person extends it with `struct A end; f(x::A, y::Integer) = 2`, a method ambiguity is caused by `f(A(), 1)`. Perhaps the aforementioned guideline only promises to avoid breaking the 1st person's code, but the 2nd person still has to understand the dispatch design if they want their new extensions to work?

Comment: I have added an example of the problem in my answer. @BatWannaBe - can you check if you get the same under Julia 1.7.0?

Comment: Ah yep it was just an older version when the method was just `propertynames(x, private)`, your example works on 1.7. Your example only shows the ambiguity affecting method calls on `T()`, so it shouldn't break pre-existing code (that is, all method calls without `T()` ), right?

Comment: In this case this is correct - it will only affect code using `T()`.